# Null Pointer Exception in Hadoop Reduce method?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm building an inverted index and currently getting a null pointer exception in reduce when using context.write. Can anyone spot why? I presume something to do with serialising as I've never done that before? The error also happens when I print out h.

Comment: it would be great if you can add a stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I've modified the code as you have suggested, other than the setClass method. Where might I override this from?

Comment: why did you edit to remove the stacktrace and code?

Comment: @vefthym Seemed the example I gave was irrelevant to the actual cause of the problem. I could put the relevant code in for brevity if preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I had iterated over the data set twice (the line `int df = Iterables.size(values);` tricked me). The iterator hadn't reset hence the main block of reduce didnt run and finally I hit a null pointer because I tried accessing my data that hadn't even initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I can spot directly regarding the serialization without a stacktrace:

1. HMapValue needs a default constructor, it can't be created by Hadoop without one
2. In the default constructor you need to initialize the `ArrayListWritable` correctly (not null and it needs the `setClass` method to deserialize correctly.